# .NETCore WCF basicHttpBinding

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-core, basichttpbinding

I'm in the process of rewriting a console application in .NET Core that calls an external web service.

I'm currently getting the following error:

> One or more errors occurred. (The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM, Negotiate'.)

I was able to resolve this in the old version of the application by updating the App.config as follows:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="EmployeeSoap" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="EmployeeSoap1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="EmployeeSoap12">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpsTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://..." binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EmployeeSoap" contract="TEST.EmployeeSoap" name="EmployeeSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I can't seem to find any good resources to show my how to accomplish this in .NET Core. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

I had a related issue with getting **System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding** to resolve correctly in *.NET Core 5*.  I had to install the *Nuget package* **System.ServiceModel.Http**.

This corrected a problem with the *Connected Services*, after attempting to add a new Connected Service with *Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider*.  After setting the endpoint and generating the connection reference, the *References.cs* could not build.  Adding this package fixed the problem.